# Command line tool to auto generate doxygen skeleton headers

Tags: c++, command-line, source-code, code-beautification

I am looking for a command line tool (Unix/Linux) that given a path to a file will find all classes/functions that are not yet documented and insert a header skeleton.

For example:

```
int myFunction(string str, uint i) {/*definition*/}
```

Would become:

```
/**
 * @brief [empty]
 *
 * @param str [empty]
 * @param i [empty]
 * @return [empty]
*/
int myFunction(string str, uint i) {/*definition*/}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but several IDEs have plugins including doxygen comment template generation. For example, eclox in Eclipse, when you start a comment with `/**` and press Enter, will generate the kind of comment you listed in your question.